# Incorrect x and y-axis values of contour2D plot

Tags: r, plot, intervals, contour, axes

I would like to see the density of my data so I drew a contour plot using the data pre-processed by `cut` function, this is a small sample of my data:

```
> z[1:2,]
           pc2_cut
pc1_cut         (-1.61,-1.45] (-1.45,-1.3] (-1.3,-1.15] (-1.15,-1] (-1,-0.851]
(-1.58,-1.38]             0            1            1          0           0
(-1.38,-1.18]             5            1            4          1           0
```

I used `plot3D` library and,

```
> contour2D(z,border="black",xlab="PC1",ylab="PC2")
```

This is what I got:

[image]

You can see the x-axis and y-axis values are incorrect, not even near the midpoint of the intervals. Does anyone know how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contour2D()` function scales the axes between 0 and 1 by default. To get different axes you can omit axes from the original `contour2D()` call and add them using `axis()` with `at` and `labels` specified. If you are using the `factors` from `cut()` you will have to convert them to numeric values before plotting. I have provided an example below where I generate data, plot it, and then adjust the axes labels after converting the factors into numeric values. Without your exact data format I do not know the best way to extract tick mark labels from your data.

[image]

```
# library for plot
library(plot3D)

# setting seed and generating some data
set.seed(10)

#### storing data in matrix ####
datamatrix <- matrix(c(rnorm(500,-1,.4),rnorm(500,2,0.2),runif(500,-3,0),runif(500,0,3)),nrow=1000,ncol=2,byrow=F)

# locations of cuts
xcuts <- seq(min(datamatrix[,1]),max(datamatrix[,1]),length.out = 6)
ycuts <- seq(min(datamatrix[,2]),max(datamatrix[,2]),length.out = 6)

# calculating values for cutting
xvals <- cut(datamatrix[,1], xcuts)
yvals <- cut(datamatrix[,2], ycuts)

# initializing matrix to store count in each bin
z <- matrix(0,length(levels(yvals)),length(levels(xvals)))

for(i in 1:length(levels(xvals))){
  for(j in 1:length(levels(yvals))){
    z[j,i] <- length(intersect(which(xvals == levels(xvals)[i]),which(yvals == levels(yvals)[j])))
  }
}

#### finding labels from factors cut ####
factsx <- levels(xvals) # factsx <- levels_pc2_cut # or something like that
xlabsFacts <- rep(NA,length(factsx))

for(i in 1:(length(factsx))){

  comma_sep <- unlist(gregexpr(pattern =',',factsx[i])) # location of the comma in the factor

  #taking section of text and converting to numbers
  xlabsFacts[i] <- as.numeric(substr(factsx[i],2,comma_sep-1))
  xlabsFacts[i+1] <- as.numeric(substr(factsx[i],comma_sep+1,nchar(factsx[i])-1))

}

factsy <- levels(yvals) # factsy <- levels_pc1_cut # or something like that
ylabsFacts <- rep(NA,length(factsy))

for(i in 1:(length(factsy))){

  comma_sep <- unlist(gregexpr(pattern =',',factsy[i])) # location of the comma in the factor

  #taking section of text and converting to numbers
  ylabsFacts[i] <- as.numeric(substr(factsy[i],2,comma_sep-1)) 
  ylabsFacts[i+1] <- as.numeric(substr(factsy[i],comma_sep+1,nchar(factsy[i])-1))

}


#### formatting plot ####
# contour plot without axes
contour2D(z
          ,yaxt='n' # no y axis ticks
          ,xaxt='n' # no x axis ticks
          ,ylab='y values' # y axis label
          ,xlab='x values' # x axis label
)

# adding x axis with tick marks
axis(side=1 # bottom
     ,at=seq(0,1,length.out = length(xlabsFacts)) # change 6 to number of tick marks you want
     ,labels=round(xlabsFacts,2) # change to labels for tick marks from your data
)

# adding x axis with tick marks
axis(side=2 # bottom
     ,at=seq(0,1,length.out = length(ylabsFacts)) # change 6 to number of tick marks you want
     ,labels=round(ylabsFacts,2) # change to labels for tick marks from your data

)
```

Comment: I managed to omit the axes from contour2D but when I adding the x axis by > axis(side=1,at=seq(0,1,length.out=9),labels=round(pc2_cut,2)), I got this error: Error in Math.factor(c(10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L,  : ‘round’ not meaningful for factors. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: @HYY, check `class(pc_cut)`. If it is a `"character"`, then `R` is treating it as a string. Two options to work around this are to specify the locations for `cut()`, and then you can use these in the `labels` argument with round. If you don't want to do that you will probably have to use `substr()` to take number portion, and then `as.numeric()` to make it a value that can be rounded. You could also just use `substr()` if you don't want to round because the labels can be strings.

Comment: I checked, it is factor.

Comment: Okay. You could use `labels=pc2_cut` and that will simply plot the factor values (intervals) at the tick marks. If you want something different than that you will probably have to reformat the factor values into a numeric format. You could always try and specify the locations for the `cut()` so that you will have numeric values that you can use in labeling.

Comment: A new section of code is included in the answer that should process the factor levels and convert them into the labels.

Comment: If it worked please upvote and accept the answer. Thanks.